# How do I use a pointer variable with consteval in c++20?

Tags: c++, c++20

I want to use a pointer variable in a consteval expression. Just like this:

```
consteval int foo(int i) { return i * i; }
consteval int bar(int* i) { return (*i) * (*i); }

int main() {
  const int const_int{8};
  const int* const_int_ptr{&const_int};

  constexpr int i = foo(const_int); //fine
  constexpr int m = bar(const_int_ptr); // does not compile

  return 0;
}
```

You can [see online at Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/hjZ-4G) that the code for `bar` does not compile. How can I fix the code for `bar`?

Comment: First thing's first, `bar` takes an `int*` but `const_int_ptr` is of type `const int*`.

Comment: Under the right circumstances, targeting the right platform, the *linker* might know the address of `const_int` - but I don't think the *compiler* ever could. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you just have a type error. `bar()` takes an `int*` but `const_int_ptr` is an `int const*`.

Once you fix that, in order to use pointers to constant expressions the pointer *and the thing it refers to* must also be constant expressions. Neither of those is true right now.  If you make the pointer itself `constexpr`, you'll get a more localized error:

```
<source>:7:38: error: '& const_int' is not a constant expression
    7 |   constexpr const int* const_int_ptr{&const_int};
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~
```

In order to have that, the address must be known - it must have static storage duration. The specific rule here is [[expr.const]/11](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#11.2):

> if the value is of pointer type, it contains the address of an object with static storage duration, the address past the end of such an object ([expr.add]), the address of a non-immediate function, or a null pointer value,

You have a pointer to `const_int`, which doesn't have static storage duration, so it's not usable in a constant expression. Make `const_int` a `static constexpr` variable, make the pointer itself `constexpr` as well (and fix the signature of `bar`) and you're good to go: [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/NyzpCh).